# Can the email recipient view emails sent to other recepient with the same subject

Tags: email

I sent an email to five different newspapers entitled: '*Company Name* - Article Enquiry', and in my sent box it grouped these messaged and displayed them as though they were all part of one conversation. Implying that all five recipients could view all five emails; so can all recipients view all emails sent with that subject? I know the answer is most likely a **resounding** no, however for some unknown reason this has confused me.

Comment: The current web site is for programming questions. I'd suggest asking non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com web site instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily check this, by throwing a look at the emails you sent. If the other recipients do not show up in some "to:" or "cc:" line, they didn't get the mail.

How your mail client decides about what a thread is might be a different story though.